# Auto Increment Gaps when using INSERT ... SELECT even with innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0

Tags: mysql

I get gaps in my auto-incremented keys, even with

```
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0
```

I isolated the problem to a single INSERT ... SELECT statement. Basically, every INSERT ... SELECT statement increments the auto_increment of the table by one **even when no insert is actually performed** (duplicate key). In my case, I use INSERT IGNORE, but I tested without and auto_increment is still wrongly incremented.

I worry about this because this INSERT ... SELECT statement runs with somewhat high-frequency so keys are getting large quickly.

I'll live with it if there's no way around, but is there any way to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug. See this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61058

...You can avoid it using:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

after every `insert...select`
However it is not that good idea because `alter table` creates temporary table, copies data and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a common problem in mysql. Personaly I just live with it.